# Requesting info from Service de publicité foncière - France

Tags: france

Is "demande d’extrait de matrice cadastrale" (https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/R18819) a right form to request info on property ownership in France? If not - what is? If it is, will it work if only either a reference cadastrale/addresse or personne inscrite, but not both is known? What kind of a mandate is required from an applicant?

Comment: Also see related answer [here](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/13882/15178), on how to obtain info on property ownership in France.

Answer (score 2):

The document you are mentioning in your question will only tell you who is paying taxes on a given property, so it might either be outdated or not reflecting the real owner(s).

The way to be sure of the owner of a property is to go to the [service de publicité foncière](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F17759). This can be accomplished remotely or by going to the appropriate office. There's usually a fee associated with these requests. It is unfortunately not clear which of the proposed forms will be required for the purpose of identifying the owner.

You can identify address, cadastral section and number from the [cadastre website](https://www.cadastre.gouv.fr/scpc/accueil.do) or [geoportail](http://www.geoportail.gouv.fr/accueil).

See related question [here](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/3156/proof-of-property-ownership-for-a-landlord-in-france).

Comment: Thanks.  It seems that these forms won't work when only owner's name and commune where property is located are known, but property address and cadastral reference are unknown.  Or am I reading it incorrectly?  Is there a way to search for properties based on owner's name?  Thanks again.